# Android on ADB returns "DEVICE NOT FOUND" in Recovery

Tags: android, root

I am experiencing this issue where I am unable to get ADB to recognize my device when its at Recovery screen. It works during normal mode, as well as Sideload mode, but not at recovery. Other guides have suggested me to update drivers, but I am using Ubuntu 22.10.
Can someone please help me?